# ssh immediately closes connection after tar backup

Tags: ssh, tar

I have seen a similar issue posted elsewhere, but mine seems to be slightly different. I am sshing into a Ubuntu 16 server, and it was working literally hours ago. I started a backup using

`tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /`

(I'm worried now because I didn't include the `exclude` flag, which seems like it may have resulted in an issue. My theory is that the backup included itself, taking up space until the disk was full.)

I left this backup running with `screen`. **I am now able to ssh in, but the connection is immediately closed.** Here is the output with `-vvv`:

```
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 128.138.229.184 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 128.138.229.184 [128.138.229.184] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 128.138.229.184:22 as 'mginn'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from 128.138.229.184
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:nNAFge1goZ9nuPuB49e/JeStkOeG7gY20U0A8CIwlrc
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from 128.138.229.184
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '128.138.229.184' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:MJa9ZCJ1R44hgE9ma0fpcgiu7fCrp8ioNW1ddAvNzM4
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:MJa9ZCJ1R44hgE9ma0fpcgiu7fCrp8ioNW1ddAvNzM4
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/milesper/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:MJa9ZCJ1R44hgE9ma0fpcgiu7fCrp8ioNW1ddAvNzM4
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with RSA SHA256:MJa9ZCJ1R44hgE9ma0fpcgiu7fCrp8ioNW1ddAvNzM4
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:MJa9ZCJ1R44hgE9ma0fpcgiu7fCrp8ioNW1ddAvNzM4
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to 128.138.229.184 ([128.138.229.184]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:9LlJzfm3JZJatDtV1wrkeYPOfrvnXGvM0iMhkinLLS0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received DSA key SHA256:rV/AvtW5tqEuf21sl2El6jZT2FgEv7ZIkUS4/kR781o
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: ssh-dss key not permitted by HostkeyAlgorithms
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:Dk9cDgvAFGnCCRAtiPmifbY25oeqekXgwuIW6YR+j8I
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:nNAFge1goZ9nuPuB49e/JeStkOeG7gY20U0A8CIwlrc
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts for 128.138.229.184 / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key at /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts2 for 128.138.229.184 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /Users/milesper/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 0 new, 3 retained, 0 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env __CFBundleIdentifier
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env ANDROID_SDK
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_EXE
debug3: Ignored env _CE_M
debug3: Ignored env _CE_CONDA
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PYTHON_EXE
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER
debug3: Ignored env PYTORCH_ENABLE_MPS_FALLBACK
debug3: Ignored env GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR_CONDA_BACKUP
debug3: Ignored env GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR
debug3: Ignored env rvm_prefix
debug3: Ignored env rvm_path
debug3: Ignored env rvm_bin_path
debug3: Ignored env rvm_version
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-142-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

69 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x00/0x00)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to 128.138.229.184 closed.
Transferred: sent 3436, received 3212 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 25656.7, received 23984.1
debug1: Exit status -1
```

It does not work to run commands with `ssh user@server "rm -f /backup.tar.gz"`.

Did I seriously mess something up with my backup operation? Is it recoverable?

Comment: Which directory were you in when you ran this command? Is this directory on the same filesystem as `/`?

Comment: Yes, I ran `tar` from `/`

Comment: This is presumably the problem, as I didn't realize that tar would include the backup folder as it was created, so it presumably endlessly backed up itself

Answer (score 1):

> My theory is that the backup included itself, taking up space until the disk was full... I left this backup running with screen.... I am now able to ssh in but the connection is immediately closed

from what you indicate, you cannot simply ssh in and to a `df -h` to see if `/` or `/home` is 100% full.  I experience this often at work when the operating system disk fills up, sometimes `/home` is under the root partition other times its on a separate partition.  When the `/` *root* partition is 100% full all kinds of dysfunctional things begin to happen, such as ssh not working (as well as vnc which users use to remote into linux servers with).

If `/home` is on a separate partition  that alleviates problems a little bit however i would speculate that if `/home` is on a separate partition and is 100% full that leaves no space left for the `.ssh` folder under a user's home account that gets used by ssh so maybe is a cause for what you are experiencing.  If your `/home` is not a separate partition and your `/` is 100% full then that's problem number 1.

In any case, if you suspect your [operating system] disk is 100% full then you need to log in at the console, sometimes in single user mode, and delete what you can to make space otherwise expect all kinds of programs and services to fail.

Comment: `/home` is under root unfortunately, and this sounds like exactly what is happening. I am able to get physical access to the server to log in, so I will have to try to do that. I was hoping there was some remote solution but it seems unlikely.

Comment: then as the `/` *root* partition filled up (which includes `/home` which may or may not matter) will have created all sorts of problems with services including ssh... the ssh service is probably still running but in a dirty dysfunctional state as you are observing, so don't expect the `-vvv` error log of ssh to be too helpful, the current ssh process is currently in a broken state because of disk full

Answer (score 1):

You could try connecting to the server through SFTP. It might work even when the server isn't accepting shell sessions, and it would permit you to remove the tarfile (or some other files) to free up some disk space.

As you've indicated, the SSH debug output shows that you are connecting to the remote server and starting a session. But the session is exiting immediately, possibly due to the remote server being out of filesystem space or some other problem.

It's possible the system might accept an SFTP session. It would depend on exactly what's wrong and how SFTP is configured on the remote system. If you are able to connect through SFTP, you should be able to examine directories and either download or delete enough files to clear up some space.